# ''Leave university''

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does ''I left university'' mean ''I dropped out'' in this sentence? '

> '**When I left university** I made a decision to take up a profession in which I could be creative.''

The example is from the book *English Collocations in Use* by Michael McCarthy.

[image]

Comment: There is a mistake in the sentence you quote. leave can be graduate from.

Comment: Not necessarily - it could also mean that the writer completed their degree and graduated.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, leaving university is understood to mean graduation (followed by leaving).  There is no way of knowing for certain, though.

In Britain, it is probably more common to say "After I left university" or "After leaving university" or "After university" than to say "After I graduated from university", even though the last is clearer.

Comment: "Michael McCarthy is Emeritus Professor of Applied Linguistics at the University of Nottingham, UK. Well known as an expert on the teaching and learning of grammar and vocabulary, he is a co-author of Cambridge Grammar of English and the elementary, upper-intermediate and advanced levels of English Vocabulary in Use." - [Cambridge University Press](https://www.cambridge.org/gb/cambridgeenglish/authors/michael-mccarthy#:~:text=Michael%20McCarthy%20is%20Emeritus%20Professor,of%20English%20Vocabulary%20in%20Use.) I don't think he dropped out.

Comment: I don't think so, either, @MichaelHarvey - but the examples in the book are not necessarily sentences in which McCarthy talks about himself.

Comment: No, he wasn't  talking about himself:)  It is from a short text about a young man. I added a screenshot. I think he dropped out but in other contexts can it mean to graduate?

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I've rejected your edit, because I think the extra context (if needed) should go in the question rather than the answer.  So I've added it to your question instead.  Thanks.

Comment: As a native BrEnglish speaker, I'd find "after I graduated" to be slightly unusual, while "after I left uni", or "after uni I" to be the more common phrasings.

Comment: Yes, I agree that those are the more common phrasings.